# Where can I find the users file for FreeRADIUS in Ubuntu?

Tags: radius, freeradius

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

I'm trying to learn how to configure a RADIUS server, but I'm having trouble with creating new users to authenticate.

Almost all of the tutorials I've found online mention creating users in the `users` file, yet I can't find it anywhere.

A [tutorial](http://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/users.html) said it would be in `etc/raddb/users` but my `etc` folder doesn't have a `raddb` folder.

Any suggestions on where I can this file? I've installed FreeRADIUS via the software center and everything is set to default, **nothing** has been customized by myself, so assume the defaults.

Answer (score 4):

It should be on /etc/freeradius/users

For a general solution, if you need to search for a file installed by a given package:

```
dpkg-query --listfiles *package* | grep *file*
```

In this case:

```
dpkg-query --listfiles freeradius | grep users
```

returned:

```
/etc/freeradius/users
```

Comment: Yes, stupid debian renaming raddb to freeradius, grrr.